# Need to combine two csv files with same number of columns but different headers using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two input csv files as below:

File1.csv

1. Actor,Movie,Director
2. Keanu Reeves,John Wick,Chad Stahelski
3. Tom Cruise‎,Jack Reacher,Christopher McQuarrie
4. Rowan Atkinson,Johnny English,Peter Howitt

File2.csv

1. Chris Pine,Jack Ryan,Kenneth Branagh
2. Matt Damon,Jason Bourne,Paul Greengrass
3. Ian Somerhalder,Marco Polo,Kevin Connor

Expected output:

Combine_File1_and_File2.csv

1. Actor,Movie,Director
2. Keanu Reeves,John Wick,Chad Stahelski
3. Tom Cruise‎,Jack Reacher,Christopher McQuarrie
4. Rowan Atkinson,Johnny English,Peter Howitt
5. Chris Pine,Jack Ryan,Kenneth Branagh
6. Matt Damon,Jason Bourne,Paul Greengrass
7. Ian Somerhalder,Marco Polo,Kevin Connor

Both csv files - File1.csv and File2.csv have same number of columns (ie. 3) but the first row in both the csv files are different (File1.csv have header and File2.csv do not have header). I need to combine the two csv in such a way that the combined file have all data from both csv files with proper header.

Comment: Load this two csv file into a list , use extend method to combine list then perform write operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.read_csv('File1.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('File2.csv', header=None)

file2.columns=file1.columns
data_final = pd.concat([file1, file2]).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks Dhaval Taunk,
Below is the final working Code:

import pandas as pd
filee1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Cypher\file1.csv')
filee2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Cypher\file2.csv',header=None)

filee2.columns=filee1.columns
data_final = pd.concat([filee1, filee2])
data_final.to_csv(r'C:\Cypher\combineF1F2.csv',index=False)

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
import pandas as pd
filee1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Cypher\file1.csv')
filee2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Cypher\file2.csv',header=None)
filee2.columns=filee1.columns
data_final = pd.concat([filee1, filee2])
data_final.to_csv(r'C:\Cypher\combineF1F2.csv',index=False)
```